# how i set the pagination in the admin in magento2 in custom module?

Tags: magento2, grid

pagination is not working in custom module in admin in magento 2[image]

please tell me how it work in magento 2

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Color;

/**
 * Adminhtml news pages grid
 */
class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
     */
    protected $moduleManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory]
     */
    protected $_setsFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type
     */
    protected $_type;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status
     */
    protected $_status;
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_visibility;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory
     */
    protected $_websiteFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory $setsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $type
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $status
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $visibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory,
        \Ocodewire\Designtool\Model\Resource\Color\Collection $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_websiteFactory = $websiteFactory;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->setId('productGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
         $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);

    }

    /**
     * @return Store
     */
    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        try{


            $collection =$this->_collectionFactory->load();



            $this->setCollection($collection);

            parent::_prepareCollection();

            return $this;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();die;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column $column
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if ($this->getCollection()) {
            if ($column->getId() == 'websites') {
                $this->getCollection()->joinField(
                    'websites',
                    'catalog_product_website',
                    'website_id',
                    'product_id=entity_id',
                    null,
                    'left'
                );
            }
        }
        return parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        // echo "dffdsfsd"; die;
        $this->addColumn(
            'color_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Color Id'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'color_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'color_name',
            [
                'header' => __('Color Name'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'index' => 'color_name',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'color_code',
            [
                'header' => __('Color Code'),
                'index' => 'color_code',
                'class' => 'color code',  
            ]
        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'color_code',
            [
                'header' => __('Color Code'),
                'index' => 'color_code',
                'class' => 'color code',  
            ]
        );









         $this->addColumn(
            'Edit',
            [
                'header' => __('Edit'),
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => [
                    [
                        'caption' => __('Edit'),
                        'url' => [
                            'base' => '*/*/edit',
                            'params' => ['store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store')]
                        ],
                        'field' => 'id'
                    ]
                ],
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'stores',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
            ]
        );


        /*{{CedAddGridColumn}}*/
        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
        if ($block) {
            $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

     /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('id');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'delete',
            array(
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
                'confirm' => __('Are you sure?')
            )
        );
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product|\Magento\Framework\Object $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            '*/*/edit',
            ['store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store'), 'id' => $row->getId()]
        );
    }


     public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', ['_current' => true]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your code in question

Comment: this is my code

Comment: please tell me how it work in the custom module

Answer (score 3):

Change below line

```
 $collection =$this->_collectionFactory->load();
```

To:

```
 $collection =$this->_collectionFactory->create();
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Color;

/**
 * Adminhtml news pages grid
 */
class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
     */
    protected $moduleManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory]
     */
    protected $_setsFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $_productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type
     */
    protected $_type;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status
     */
    protected $_status;
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_visibility;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory
     */
    protected $_websiteFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory $setsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $type
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $status
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $visibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory,
        \Ocodewire\Designtool\Model\Resource\Color\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_websiteFactory = $websiteFactory;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->setId('productGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
         $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);

    }

    /**
     * @return Store
     */
    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        try{

            $collection =$this->_collectionFactory->create();

            $this->setCollection($collection);

            parent::_prepareCollection();

            return $this;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();die;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column $column
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if ($this->getCollection()) {
            if ($column->getId() == 'websites') {
                $this->getCollection()->joinField(
                    'websites',
                    'catalog_product_website',
                    'website_id',
                    'product_id=entity_id',
                    null,
                    'left'
                );
            }
        }
        return parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        // echo "dffdsfsd"; die;
        $this->addColumn(
            'color_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Color Id'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'color_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'color_name',
            [
                'header' => __('Color Name'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'index' => 'color_name',
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'color_code',
            [
                'header' => __('Color Code'),
                'index' => 'color_code',
                'class' => 'color code',  
            ]
        );


        $this->addColumn(
            'color_code',
            [
                'header' => __('Color Code'),
                'index' => 'color_code',
                'class' => 'color code',  
            ]
        );









         $this->addColumn(
            'Edit',
            [
                'header' => __('Edit'),
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getId',
                'actions' => [
                    [
                        'caption' => __('Edit'),
                        'url' => [
                            'base' => '*/*/edit',
                            'params' => ['store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store')]
                        ],
                        'field' => 'id'
                    ]
                ],
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'index' => 'stores',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
            ]
        );


        /*{{CedAddGridColumn}}*/
        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
        if ($block) {
            $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

     /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('id');

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem(
            'delete',
            array(
                'label' => __('Delete'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
                'confirm' => __('Are you sure?')
            )
        );
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product|\Magento\Framework\Object $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            '*/*/edit',
            ['store' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('store'), 'id' => $row->getId()]
        );
    }


     public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', ['_current' => true]);
    }
}
```

> *The Factory class name is the name of Model class and append with the Factory word. So for our example, we will have TopicFactory class. You must not create this class. Magento will create it for you. Whenever Magento’s object manager encounters a class name that ends in the word ‘Factory’, it will automatically generate the Factory class in the var/generation folder if the class does not already exist. You will see the factory class in*

```
var/generation/<vendor_name>/<module_name>/Model/ClassFactory.php
```

> *To instantiate a model object we will use automatic constructor dependency injection to inject a factory object, then use factory object to instantiate the model object.*

[For More Click Here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/factories.html)

***I Hope This Helps You***

Answer (score 0):

It seems this file may be fine.

I would look at file like your grid layout file: specifically, are you having a formkey defined into your layout file?